# How to fill and object with data from an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Really, the question is how to fill and object with data from a string, but string to array is trivial.

I need to end up with an object thus:

```
myobject={"x":5,"y":6,"w":7,"h":8}
```

starting from a string, thus:

```
var str = "5 6 7 8"
```

My solutions so far are

```
var myarray = str.split(' ');
var myobject = {
    x : myarray[0],
    y : myarray[1],
    w : myarray[2],
    h : myarray[3]
}
```

or

```
var myarray = str.split(' ');
var mynames = ['x','y',' w','h'];
 for (var i = mynames.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    obj.[mynames[i]]=myarray[i]
 }
```

Wonder if there is a better way

Comment: map and reduce.

Comment: If you have working code which you want to improve you can post here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @yuriy636 the second example here does not work, and this is a _very_ trivial task. Code Review typically accepts more elaborate code submissions.

Comment: @T4rk1n could you provide code?

Comment: @PEWColina Josh answer is using reduce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use destructuring to assign the numbers to variables, and then assign them to the object using [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015).

```js
const str = "5 6 7 8";
const [x, y, w, h]  = str.split(' ');
const obj = { x, y, w, h };
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: This is elegant but generates a little pollution with with 4 extra variables floating around. console.log(obj,x, y, w, h);

Comment: not a big deal in small applications, but they might already be assigned const. Also I would do var [x, y, w, h]... so you can use them again

Comment: @PEWColina - they would be used inside a method, and will be garbage collected as soon as the method is done. Don't use reusable global variables, and if you need a assignable variable - use `let`. And thanks for the UV :)

Answer (score 2):

[`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is your friend:

```
var myarray = str.split(' ');
var mynames = ['x','y',' w','h'];

var obj = myarray.reduce((acc, curr, i) => {
  acc[mynames[i]] = curr
  return acc
}, {})  // => {"x":5,"y":6,"w":7,"h":8}
```

`acc` is your accumulator object (your new output), and `curr` (current) is the current item in `myarray`.

This is dependent on the order of the items in your string that you're splitting, as well as the order of `mynames`.

**Edit:** this solution is compatible with ES6 and ES5 (if you use a regular `function(){}` as the callback instead of an arrow function).

Comment: Thanks! This is interesting, although it is a bit longer and less scrutable than a loop.

Comment: @PEWColina no problem, glad you find it interesting. It is a loop (albeit, not a "for loop") and in my experience, this is a pretty "idiomatic" JavaScript for doing this kind of thing (reduce is typically used for building objects or adding up values, stuff like that).

Answer (score 0):

One option is using ES 6 [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Destructuring allows assigning multiple values in a single statement. Also, [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) *syntax* can be used for spreading the string to an array.

```js
var outputObj = {x:'', y : '', w : '', h: ''};
var stringToConvert = "5678";
[outputObj.x, outputObj.y, outputObj.w, outputObj.h]  = [...stringToConvert];
console.log(outputObj);
```